# iframe bug with audioplayer

Tags: internet-explorer

When opening a link which points directly to audioplayer, all browsers play them.  Audioplayer is 
in nested divs which is embed element pointing to swf.

But when writing  and embedding it into some page will show the player but it will not play in IE8.  Works in all other major browsers including IE9.

BTW it didn't work in Safari, but assigning width and height with large enough values fixed it for Safari, but not IE8.

```
<iframe width="500" height="50" src="http://localhost/getAudio?id=DB04DDA8-C7C9-46E6-B0B3-7A0E0B5C9A55" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">

<html class=" js no-flexbox no-canvas no-canvastext no-webgl no-touch no-geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase no-indexeddb hashchange no-history draganddrop no-websockets no-rgba no-hsla no-multiplebgs no-backgroundsize no-borderimage no-borderradius no-boxshadow no-textshadow no-opacity no-cssanimations no-csscolumns no-cssgradients no-cssreflections no-csstransforms no-csstransforms3d no-csstransitions fontface generatedcontent no-video no-audio localstorage sessionstorage no-webworkers no-applicationcache no-svg no-inlinesvg no-smil no-svgclippaths" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<HEAD>
<STYLE class=iepp-printshim media=print></STYLE>
<TITLE>Bethoven symphony # 9</TITLE>
<META charset=utf-8>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="/celenium/scripts/libs/jquery-latest.js"></SCRIPT>


<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="/celenium/scripts/ClientCompatibility.js"></SCRIPT>

<STYLE type=text/css>BODY {
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px
}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV id=asset01>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
            $.ajax({
                url: '/celenium/audioplayer_html5/getPlayer.asp?o=DB04DDA8-C7C9-46E6-B0B3-7A0E0B5C9A55',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                cache: true,
                jsonpCallback: 'sdlaudioplayer',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#asset01').append($(data.html));
                }
            });    
        </SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet href="http://localhost/celenium/audioplayer_html5/css/defaultplayer.css" media=screen>
<DIV id=sdlaudioplayer class=player_container>
<DIV class=player_metabar></DIV>
<DIV class=player_controls>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: block" class=player_controls_play jQuery1707536265854468271="1"></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" class=player_controls_pause jQuery1707536265854468271="2"></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" class=player_controls_prev jQuery1707536265854468271="3"></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" class=player_controls_next jQuery1707536265854468271="4"></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 297px; DISPLAY: block" class=player_controls_scrubber jQuery1707536265854468271="5">
<DIV class=player_controls_scrubber_loading jQuery1707536265854468271="13">
<DIV class=player_controls_scrubber_loaded></DIV>
<DIV class=player_controls_scrubber_playhead></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: block" class=player_controls_timing jQuery1707536265854468271="6"><SPAN class=player_controls_timing_position>0:00</SPAN> / <SPAN class=player_controls_timing_total>0:00</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: block" class=player_controls_volume jQuery1707536265854468271="7">
<DIV class=player_controls_volume_mute jQuery1707536265854468271="8"></DIV>
<DIV class=player_controls_volume_slider jQuery1707536265854468271="12">
<DIV style="WIDTH: 50%" class=player_controls_volume_marker jQuery1707536265854468271="11"></DIV>
<DIV style="LEFT: 28px" class=player_controls_volume_knob jQuery1707536265854468271="10"></DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=player_controls_volume_max jQuery1707536265854468271="9"></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV id=sm2-container class="high_performance movieContainer swf_loaded"><!-- SM2 flash goes here -->
<DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=sm2-object-box>
<OBJECT id=sm2movie title="JS/Flash audio component (SoundManager 2)" codeBase="download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" classid=clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000 data="/celenium/audioplayer_html5/swf/soundmanager2_flash9.swf" width=auto type=application/x-shockwave-flash height=auto></OBJECT></DIV></DIV></DIV></BODY>
```

Comment: Posting code is always necessary. It would be like asking a mechanic to fix your car, but by leaving the car in your locked garage with no gasoline and ignition keys. :)

Comment: Here you go.  We have two calls.  First by iframe, second by ajax.  That ajax fills innerHTML for div below.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 is not considered a modern browser in that it doesn't support many of the HTML5 features, such as the audio and video tags.

This [HTML5 Tutorial](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-audio.php) site has an example of how to support audio in IE8, using the Object tag. See example below:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="vincent.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    <source src="vincent.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/OriginalMusicPlayer.swf" 
      width="225" height="86"> 
       <param name="movie" value="media/OriginalMusicPlayer.swf"/>
       <param name="FlashVars" value="mediaPath=vincent.mp3" /> 
    </object> 
</audio>
```

Keep in mind that this requires that the IE8 client have Flash installed, since it uses Flash to load the player.

If the client doesn't have Flash installed, your last ditch effort is to simply provide a download link and let the user use the operating system's default player to play the audio file:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="vincent.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    <source src="vincent.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/OriginalMusicPlayer.swf"  
      width="225" height="86"> 
        <param name="movie" value="media/OriginalMusicPlayer.swf"/>
        <param name="FlashVars" value="mediaPath=vincent.mp3" /> 
    </object> 
    <a href="vincent.mp3">Download this lovely song and wish you all the best!</a>
</audio>
```

As a side note, the problems your facing could very well stem from the fact that your HTML is missing an html5 doctype and contains validation errors. You may want to check the W3C spec. I believe all of your attributes should have quotes around them.

While many browsers are good at letting you make syntax and semantic mistakes in your HTML and just wing it, sometimes these validation issues can come back to haunt you. I strongly suggest you run your site against the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to make sure there aren't any HTML errors that are preventing IE8 from correctly interpreting your markup.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer.  I need at least couple of hours to recode scripts.  Our player also supports debug mode.  After turning it on, it complained that No HTML5 Audio support detected.  I don't get it where html5 though (like <audio> or <video>).  It's just bunch of divs with object for a flash player.